# Image not loaded in MvxImageView in Xamarin.android app

Tags: xamarin, imageview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MvxImageView to load images from server like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="161.9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text TextContent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shareLayout"
        android:layout_width="157.7dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58.2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
        <Mvx.MvxImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8.3dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ImageUrl"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48.1dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35.4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Earlier it was working fine but now its not loading the image. I haven't changed any thing. I have tried reinstalling DownloadCache and File Plugin but it didn't work. I have also set the permission of Internet access but it is giving following error.

mvx:Diagnostic:465.84 failed to download image http://i.space.com/images/i/000/046/083/i02/gravity-probe-b.jpg : WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)
07-17 10:14:53.784 I/mono-stdout(  396): mvx:Diagnostic:465.84 failed to download image http://i.space.com/images/i/000/046/083/i02/gravity-probe-b.jpg : WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in :0 
07-17 10:14:53.784 I/mono-stdout(  396):      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in :0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxFileDownloadRequest.ProcessResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) [0x00017] in :0 
07-17 10:14:53.784 I/mono-stdout(  396):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxFileDownloadRequest.ProcessResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) [0x00017] in :0 
InnerException was SocketException: Connection timed out
07-17 10:14:53.794 I/mono-stdout(  396): InnerException was SocketException: Connection timed out
      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f7] in :0 
07-17 10:14:53.794 I/mono-stdout(  396):      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f7] in :0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in :0 
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:465.84 failed to download image http://i.space.com/images/i/000/046/083/i02/gravity-probe-b.jpg : WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in :0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxFileDownloadRequest.ProcessResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) [0x00017] in :0 
InnerException was SocketException: Connection timed out
      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f7] in :0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in :0 
07-17 10:14:53.794 I/mono-stdout(  396):   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in

Comment: It tells you the exact error. `Connection timed out`

Comment: Yes but  I don't understand why it is happening . I have internet connection but it is not downloading the images . Is there any issue with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Install the DownloadCache plugin and MVVMCross File plugin and MVVCross.Plugin.PictureChooser